# Form with <ui:repeat> and Lists inside a List

Tags: java, jsf

I have the following problem and I'm stuck not knowing how to proceed.

I have to enter in a single form multiples objects that in there variable have a `List` for a second object but I have only to enter one object in that second list for each of the first.

```
// ObjectOne

public class ObjectOne{
   private String name;
   private List<ObjectTwo> objectsTwo;
  // getters and setters
}

// Object Two

public class ObjectTwo{
   private String name;
   private String var1;
   private String var2;
   private String var3;
  // getters and setters
}
```

I was using `<ui:repeat>` inside a form to get a the list of `ObjectsOne` and I need to create a new instances of `ObjectTwo` for each iteration of `<ui:repeat>`

```
<ui:repeat value="#{bean.objectOneList}" var="obj1">
</ui:repeat>
```

Any light in how can I accomplish that?

Comment: If in understand you well, you want to instantiate `Object Two` in the view?  If so, why this?

Comment: What I need is to create a new object two for each object one In the same view.